# Is there any point pressing ctrl+c repeatedly?

Tags: matlab, kill, sigint

Often (e.g. using matlab) I've executed some program accidentally. I try to interrupt it by hitting CTRL+C. Sometimes this works, other times it doesn't and I keep madly hitting it until the program finally stops. Are these extra ctrl+c's doing anything or is this just a rain dance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is entirely reliant upon how [`SIGINT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29#SIGINT) is handled. Chances are your subsequent <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> presses are not doing anything and you are just being impatient while the program tries to clean itself up, though it is possible that a programmer decides to ignore the first *n* <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> presses then allows *n + 1* to exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

The `^C` signal can be caught as an exception. You may hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during a section of code where that exception is caught, and it has no result. This could be intentional, or perhaps just an overly broad catch block. The next time, you may hit those keys and they'll have the desired effect.

While hammering away at those keys can work where a single press wouldn't, it's probably more indicative of software that needs some improvement than a real solution.